# What is the proper way to dismiss a modal when using storyboards?

Tags: ios, storyboard, modal-dialog

Using storyboards, what is the proper way to dismiss a modal?

- using IBAction and writing code to dismiss after a button click?
- using segue and notify the parent view controller after a button click?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See Here [Dismissing a Presented View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) about halfway down

> When it comes time to dismiss a presented view controller, the preferred approach is to let the presenting view controller dismiss it.

So you should use an IBAction and writing code to dismiss after a button click

Comment: "So you should use an IBAction and writing code to dismiss after a button click" Actually is wrong. What Apple is saying is "you need to notify the PARENT view controller which then dismisses the modal."

Comment: Link is broken nowadays

Comment: I made a category :) 
https://github.com/evanstoddard/UIViewController-Dismiss-Actions

Answer (score 16):

According Alex Cio answer for `Swift 3` and `XCode 8.3`:

Create class:

```
import UIKit

class DismissSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        self.source.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

But in storyboard you should choose:

> Action Segue -> Custom -> dismiss

Only after this option appear on `Action Segue` menu

Answer (score 15):

I've found that usually when I'm attempting to do this in storyboard I'd rather not create extra classes. It still makes sense to perform the dismiss from the presenting view controller, so that requires a class to back it.

If you create an IBAction in the presenting view controller and name it appropriately e.g.

```
- (IBAction)dismissAnyModel:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then from storyboard wherever you want to trigger the dismiss from you create an action to the first responder as shown below. You can extend this to work with multiple presenting view controllers by creating unique names for the IBActions.

[image: Create an outlet to first responder]

[image: Select correct IBAction]

[More information on first responder and the responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html)

Answer (score 10):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362749/moving-back-from-a-controller-to-a-previous-one/9363429#9363429). It gives you two ways to dismiss the modal view controller with storyboard. I like method two described because one you add the class in your project your return from modal views can be done with no code using storyboard alone. That said, if you have implemented a delegate and delegate protocol, it is also a good place to put the dismissModalViewController statement.

Answer (score 10):

To do this inside the `UIStoryboard` you need first to create an Object of the type `UIStoryboardSegue` in your project

[image: Creating a new class of type <code>UIStoryboardSegue</code>]

Then insert following method inside the class. Here is my class

@implementation DismissController

```
- (void)perform{

    UIViewController *sourceVC = self.sourceViewController;
    [sourceVC.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES 
                                                          completion:nil]; 
}
```

Now you can use it inside your `UIStoryboard`. Select the button that should make the `UIViewController` Disappear and drag it to the `UIViewController` you want to go to. In my case it shows **dismiss Controller* because of the name of my Class.

[image]

Select it and you are done!
There is also a very good explanation [on this website.](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/02/19/dismissing-a-modal-view-using-a-storyboard-segue)

Answer (score -1):

As the Apple online documentation indicates, the presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the modal (presented) view.

There's a post and example available 
[here](http://martinplatt.com/mblog/2015/04/ios-8-storyboard-with-xcode-dismissing-a-modal-view-the-right-way/)

Comment: Link obsolete. That is why you should not answer by posting a link without posting some sample codes first.