# Objective C: Back button segue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, modalviewcontroller

I have a simple app with 2 screens. 
When I press a button to go from the first to the second, everything is performed successfully (including animation). However, when I click the back button on the second screen, I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <getTextViewController: 0x8f6aa30> on <SecondViewController: 0x946cc80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

EDIT: Please don't refer me to other questions regarding above warning - I already saw those, and they refer to other issues.

However, it still switches back to the first screen. Yet, the animation of the segue does not perform. 
Also: Information (such as inputted text) in the first screen remains when I return to the first screen, while information in the second screen resets every time the screen comes up.

Here is how I call both operations:

```
Segue from View 1 to View 2:
Name: F21, Style: Modal, Transition: Cross Dissolve, Animation: True.

Segue from View 2 to View 1:
Name: F12, Style: Modal, Transition: Cross Dissolve, Animation: True.
```

Code in getTextViewController.m (View 1):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"F21"]){
    UIViewController *v = [segue destinationViewController];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    v = self;

}
}
-(void)performSegue:(NSString*)str{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:str sender:self];
}
//In some other method:
[self performSegue:@"F21"];
```

Code in SecondViewController.m (View 2):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"F12"]){
    UIViewController *v = [segue destinationViewController];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    v = self;

}
}
-(void)performSegue:(NSString*)str{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:str sender:self];
}
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
[self performSegue:@"F12"];

}
```

I would very much appreciate any help to understand why the first segue works while the second doesn't.

Thank you,

Dean

NOTE: Here is the full project - https://github.com/dean13-meet/firstIOSApp
EDIT: Updated git.

Comment: Your github project is missing the getTextViewController .h and .m files.

Comment: Why do you even need a back segue? This functionality is built-in! You get your error message because you dismiss your `SecondVC` and then try to present a new `VC` from that dismissed `VC`.

Comment: Don't use segue for coming back to 1st view from 2nd view controller and simply use a [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil] method which u had used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not exactly sure what you're trying to do in your `prepareForSegue`, their is no need to be dismissing VC's there. If you want to have a simple app where you go from VC1 to VC2 and then back again, your best bet is to use a `segue` and an `unwindSegue`.

So in your storyboard control drag from a button on VC1 to VC2 and select your segue type. Then in VC1.m setup the unwind segue such as:

```
 - (IBAction)unwindFromViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
 {
    //empty implementation
 }
```

Finally, in your VC2 control drag from the back button to the green exit icon on VC2 and select your `unwindFromViewController` method.

That should do what you're looking for.

Comment: This works! However, it does not retain the information entered in VC2 --- I have a Label in VC2, and everytime I re-enter that view, the Label resets its value. Is it possible to make it that VC2 will remain the same when exited? In other words, keep the same Object reference?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, I would suggest using a push segue opposed to modal because it takes care of all the back buttons for you. If you don't like the idea of a navigation controller however, try dismissing the view with the following: [Moving back from a Controller to a previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362749/moving-back-from-a-controller-to-a-previous-one/9363429#9363429)