# Need To Pass The Value From B Viewcontroller to A Viewcontroller Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am struggling on calling method from `viewController B` to `viewController A`. Need to call `viewController B` close button click to `Dismissviewcontroller` then immediately need to call one method and want to pass two string values on `viewController A`. Its like reverse process.

FYI : I am using `Storyboard` and present viewController for B. A is the `mainviewcontroller`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362749/moving-back-from-a-controller-to-a-previous-one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: Use NSNotificationCenter Or Delegate .

Answer (score 0):

- use `viewWillAppear` in controller `A`.
- Post a notification from controller `B` and add
  observer on controller `A`.

Post notification on controller `B` close button 
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:"NAME" object:nil userInfo:nil];`

Add observer on controller `A`:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(perform:) name:@"NAME" object:nil];`

- Implement delegates on
  controller `B` and implement it on controller `A` so once you click
  on close button controller `B` just call the delegate and perform what ever you want.
- Implement `KVO`

Comment: Please pose some sample code. I am little in objective C so please!

Answer (score 0):

There are many option for passing values

1. Use protocol and delegates
2. Use unwind segues
3. Use Notifications

there are many other option to do the same google on above points you will get tons of demos for this.

Answer (score 0):

well the easiest way but not the most efficient is to make a global object of the `viewController A`  and `viewController A` view did load method 
call that global variable and make it equal to self and 
in then  the dismiss from `viewController B`

will use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{


  // here you can create a code for calling the global **viewController A** object to call the function you need

}];
```

conclusion :

in `viewController A` header file :

```
extern A* AGlobalInstance;
```

and in A.m file just below the `#import "A.h"`

```
A* AGlobalInstance;
```

and in the `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  AGlobalInstance = self;
}
```

then in B.m button just use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [AGlobalInstance function];
 }];
```

but you must go to A viewController first before going to B to make it work

Comment: this is objective c >__<

Answer (score 0):

As the above answers suggested you to use  Delegates and Notification so I am not gonna suggest you those. Apart from them I would like to ask you to go for `Block`.

```
typedef void(^valueHandler)(id anyObject1, id anyObject2);
```

**@viewController A**

```
B *instanceOfB;
[instanceOfB setValueHandlerBlock^(id anyObject1, id anyObject2) {
// Here you can receive the values.
}];
```

**@viewController B**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) valueHandler valueHandlerBlock;

//To pass the value
if (valueHandlerBlock) {
    valueHandlerBlock(@"a String value", anArray);
    // When ever the above line will execute it will pass the values to view controller A.
}
```

Comment: are you sure he won't need to set `instanceOfB` to equal self in B view controller first , to connect them together ?

Comment: I think you should go through https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html this first.

Comment: typedef where I want to put?@Tapas Pal

Comment: @Sanju you can add anywhere I mean which will be global accessible. But in this case you can add at the top of `@viewController B` interface in .h file.